# How to get the XML Node via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have a XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
    <Class>
        <Room>
            1
        </Room>
        <Subject>
            English
        </Subject>
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <Room>
            2
        </Room>
        <Subject>
            Maths
        </Subject>
    </Class>
</Root>
```

I am using it as a datasource for my grid , i have used xmldatasource and xpath for that .

```
PrimaryDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
PrimaryDataSource.EnableCaching = false;
PrimaryDataSource.Data = ClassXML;
return PrimaryDataSource;
```

and accessing the nodes in client side as:
XPath("Room") & XPath("Subject")

Which gives me the values of that particular attributes.

Now i want to get the whole XML root form client side, one `Class` root only.

```
<Class>
    <Room>
        1
    </Room>
    <Subject>
        English
    </Subject>
</Class>
```

Can anybody tell me how can i get it thru XPath or other methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first "class" just use:

```
(//Class)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one root, you can also use XPATH:

```
/Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select *all* classes using an absolute XPath expression:

```
/Root/Class
```

or a *descendant* axis expression like:

```
//Class
```

which will select a node-set containing *all* classes, independend of their nesting (if there are `Class` elements deeper in the hierarchy, they will also be selected in this case.

With a *positional predicate* like the one suggested in the answer by @ErezRobinson, you can select the classes according to their position in a *context*. The parentheses will place it in a *global context*. Every slash-separated step in an XPath expression provides a context which limits the scope of the following step or the following predicate. And each predicate reduces the node set by filtering out nodes that don't match the boolean expression inside it. `(//Class)[1]` is a shortcut for `(//Class)[position() = 1]`

You can also select a class matching the values of its children nodes with a predicate. To select all `Class` elements that have a *child element* `Room` with the value of `2`, you can use:

```
//Class[Room = '2']
```

You can also select by Subject:

```
//Class[Subject = 'Maths']
```

Finally, once you have a context, you can select other elements within that scope. For example, you can get the `Room` number when the `Subject` is `English`:

```
//Class[Subject = 'English']/Room
```

The `Class[Subject = 'English']` step in this case just *creates a context* for the next step, which effectively selects a node or node set.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions , but it didnt works for me. what i want is : This XML has one ROOT name as Root , and two sub root Class[1] and Class[2] , I want to get one of the Class root , i mean the whole XML which has root "Class" , i am not interested only in the values of element i want the the whole part of xml.

Comment: In that case, the answer by @RoeiFinkelstein should solve your problem.